# Firebase Authentication Failing with flutter app

Tags: flutter

Firebase Authentication with flutter app failing with the error below
Launching lib/main.dart on TECNO LA7 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/mac/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
Syncing files to device TECNO LA7...
D/HWUIExtension(11822): MTKProgramCache.generateProgram: 562984313159681
D/HWUIExtension(11822): createProgram 0x0002000800000001, binary 0x8517f6c8, length 11771, format 37168 within 1349ns
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11822): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11822): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11822): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:269)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.getAuth(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:78)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:119)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
I/flutter (11822): Error: PlatformException(error, FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. , null)
I/zygote  (11822): Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
I/zygote  (11822): After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
I/zygote  (11822): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.01 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 41% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:269)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.getAuth(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:78)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:119)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(11822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
I/flutter (11822): Error: PlatformException(error, FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. , null)
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.22 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 41% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 41% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 42% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 42% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 42% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 42% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LucidStats currentFPS = 2.00 [2305329520]
E/libPowerStretch(11822): LUCID Battery Level = 42% Battery Temp = -100 Cpu Temp = -100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure about this, I need Verification
I updated the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file 
in android/app/src/main/java/io.flutter.plugins/ folder and some how firebase authentication worked

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit more detail about what code is causing this error it's very difficult to say, but the error appears to indicate that there isn't a firebase app configured for this application - "FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist."

I'd suggest checking your app configuration, and checking it matches the app details in firebase console.

Comment: I did check the firebase app configurations from the firebase console and  every thing there seems okay